# How to disable urllib3 Retrying warning messages?

Tags: python-2.7, robotframework, urllib3

How to disable urllib3 Retrying warning messages?

> [ WARN ] Retrying (Retry(total=9, connect=None, read=None,
>   redirect=None)) after connection broken by
>   'NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection:
>   [Errno 111] Connection refused',)'

I am getting thousands of Warning messages while executing my testcase because it has many URI POST/PATCH operation on a given unit.

Due to this effect the log file size was increasing drastically.

Is there any possibility to remove/disable warning message when NewConnectionError ?

I have tried to disable warning message from NewConnectionError, It's not working.

```
from requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import NewConnectionError
requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(NewConnectionError)
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
import logging
logging.getLogger("urllib3").setLevel(logging.ERROR)
```

Comment: Thanks @Paul, Still i am getting same warning message

Comment: Op's logger is imported from a vendored package inside of requests, so the path is not just "urllib3" unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

The warning you're seeing is *caused* by a `NewConnectionError` but it's not actually a *emitted* `warning`  but rather a `log.warn(...)`. You can raise the urllib3 logging level to get rid of it.

Because you're using urllib3 that is vendored inside of requests and the logger takes its name from the package path, it's "requests.packages.urllib3" rather than just "urllib3". This value is evident from the `requests.packages.urllib3.__package__` variable.

```
import logging
import requests
logging.getLogger(requests.packages.urllib3.__package__).setLevel(logging.ERROR)
```

Answer (score 0):

I could able to slove with below snippet

```
requests_log = logging.getLogger("requests")
requests_log.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
requests_log.propagate = True
```